# How can I automatically increment a date in word so I can have the same form for different days

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a form for each day of the month. I want to repeat the form and have word increment the date and day of week automatically.
I know how to do it with excel with the +1 but not in word.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you either have to do this in VBA or another programming language, or use some nested field codes. Either way, it's not completely automatic. Just using field codes, you can do it like this:

On the first page, use

```
{ SET dfmt "DD-MMMM-YYYY" }{ DATE \@{ REF dfmt } }{ SET cd { DATE } }{ SET d { REF cd \@D } }{ SET m { REF cd \@M } }{ SET y { REF cd \@YYYY } }
```

On each page after that, use

```
{ SET d { =d+1 } }{ IF "{ QUOTE "{ =y }-{ =m }-{ =d }" \@"DD-MM-YYYY" }" = "{ QUOTE "{ =y }-{ =m }-{ =d }" }" "{ SET d 1 }{ IF { =m } = 12 "{ SET m 1 }{ SET y { =y+1 } }" "{ SET m { =m+1 }" }" }" }{ QUOTE "{ =y }-{ =m }-{ =d }" \@{ REF dfmt } }
```

Some notes:

You can insert all the special field brace pairs {} using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word. Using the ordinary keyboard characters won't work. You can use ALt-F9 to toggle field code/field result display on and off.

You need to select the whole document (e.g. using ctrl-A) and update *all* the field values (e.g. using F9) to update all the dates correctly. i.e. it's not completely automatic. You have to do them all at the same time or there may be inconsistencies. Further, when you *print*, Word updates some field codes (e.g. REF) whatever the setting is for "Update fields on print", but only updates others (e.g. + and SET) when Update fields on print is set to True. Using { =y } etc. instead of { y } or { REF y } works around that.

I use dfmt to specify the date format you actually want to use to display the date. The format options should still be documented in Help somewhere.

The IF field works by comparing a candidate field, formatted with a date format, with the unformatted field. If the candidate is a valid date, then the format is applied and so { QUOTE "2013-9-30" \@"DD-MM-YYYY" } returns "30-09-2013". If it isn't a valid date, the format is not applied, so { QUOTE "2013-9-31" \@"DD-MM-YYYY" } returns "2013-9-31" In other words, the two comparands are only equal when the 'date' is not valid.

AS far as I know, Word always interprets a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD correctly, regardless of your regional options.

If you prefer fewer spaces you can cut these field sequences to

```
{SET dfmt "DD-MMMM-YYYY"}{DATE \@{REF dfmt}}{SET cd {DATE}}{SET d {REF cd \@D}}{SET m {REF cd \@M}}{SET y {REF cd \@YYYY}}
```

and

```
{SET d {=d+1}}{IF "{QUOTE "{=y}-{=m}-{=d}" \@"DD-MM-YYYY"}" = "{QUOTE "{=y}-{=m}-{=d}"}" "{SET d 1}{IF {=m} = 12 "{SET m 1}{SET y {=y+1}}" "{SET m {=m+1}"}"}"}{QUOTE "{=y}-{=m}-{=d}" \@{REF dfmt}}
```

You can cut more out if you want but I leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will insert the date, and everytime you open the doc, the date should adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I assume lmgtfy isn't allowed here. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-the-date-and-time-to-a-word-2010-docume.html

1. `Insert -> Date & Time -> Select a format -> [x] Update automatically -> OK`
2. Hotkeys

   **Insert date**
   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

   **Insert time**
   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. `Insert -> Quick Parts -> Field -> Date and Time -> PrintDate -> Select a format`

Comment: Correct, its not allowed. And a summary of your link is also much appreciated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: Super, this will add the date but how do I automatically increment the date by 1 on the second page, by 2 on the third page, etc.?